# Error when selecting second item from ListView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a list view with the multiselect property set to false. When the user clicks on it, I take the NAME property of the list view item and convert it to a decimal then feed that to a method that loads the correct record.

The code below works perfectly when I select one item regardless of how many items are in the list and regardless of which item I select.

```
        private void ListInstruments_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem selection = listInstruments.SelectedItems[0];
            if (selection != null)
            {
                 string strSelection = selection.Name;
                 SelectedInstrumentID = Convert.ToDecimal(strSelection);
                 LoadSelectedInstrument();                
            }
        }
```

When I make a second selection (not multi-select, but a different selection from the listbox) I get an error referencing `listInstruments.SelectedItems[0]`.

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException Message=InvalidArgument=Value of
>   '0' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index
>   Source=System.Windows.Forms

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: instead of SelectedItems[0], check whether you can grab the index from the EventArgs e. Something like e.Index or something else? and use it in SelectedItems[e.Index]

Comment: I am going to give this a try, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, that *no items* are selected, and thus `list.SelectedItems` is *empty*; you are tring to get `0`th item from the *empty* collection and thus have the *exception thrown*. The quick patch is

```
 // instead of original
 // ListViewItem selection = listInstruments.SelectedItems[0];
 ListViewItem selection = list.SelectedItems.Count > 0 
   ? listInstruments.SelectedItems[0] // the collection has at least one item
   : null;                            // if the collection is empty
```

Or we can check if we have a selection and `return` when there's none

```
 private void ListInstruments_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (list.SelectedItems.Count <= 0)   
        return; 

    listViewItem selection = listInstruments.SelectedItems[0];

    string strSelection = selection.Name;
    SelectedInstrumentID = Convert.ToDecimal(strSelection);
    LoadSelectedInstrument();  
 }
```

Comment: that's what I thought, but it seems like white space clicks are handled by the is not null check, I just do it a little differently.

I am definitely making a selection on a list view item.

Comment: oh wait, I see what you mean. Because the declaration is failing it never makes it to the null check.

Comment: @Ray Delien: you are trying to get `0`th item from the *empty* collection, since the collection *doesn't have* `0`th item (it's empty) you have the exception thrown

Comment: [not challenging just learning] How could the collection be empty when the event is triggered by selecting a list box item?

Comment: @Ray Delien: please, note, that event is `SelectedIndexChanged`, so when you *unselect* an item `SelectedIndex` *changes* from, say, `123` (previously selected item index) to `-1` (no items are selected) and the event will be fired (with empty `list.SelectedItems` collection)

Comment: You were right, I am now able to select items normally.